# Can groupByKey be used to optimize and reduce computation work

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have Dataframe something like this

empId|firstName|lastName|DOB|effStartDate|effEndDate|........

121|Rahul|Jaiswal|27-10-1194|03-05-2019|03-05-2020|.....

147|Dev|Kumar|12-03-1995|04-08-2019|03-05-2020|.....

121|Rahul|Jaiswal|27-10-1194|03-05-2019|03-05-2020|.....

...
...continue

Right now, I am extracting value from the DF something like this:

```
  implicit val encoder = kryo[EmployeeJobDataFields]
val sortedDF = df.orderBy(asc(EMP_ID_COLUMN), asc(EFF_START_DATE_COLUMN)).na.fill(EMPTY_STRING)
   val recordList: List[EmployeeJobDataFields] = sortedDF
  .map(row => {
    EmployeeJobDataFields(row.getString(0), row.getString(1), row.getString(2), row.getString(3),
      row.getString(4), row.getString(5), row.getString(6), row.getString(7), row.getString(8), row.getString(9)
  })(encoder)
  .collectAsList
```

Here, empId will repeat for some user

Is this the best way to do it or can we have any other way to enhance the code?
I am not sure will groupByKey() fit here and reduce any kind of computation works

Expert, please guide me